# Loader timing issues

Tags: html, css, animation, loader

I am confused why the after selector is moving faster than the no selector div, can anyone explain why this is the case? The before and after selectors are working perfectly but I cannot seem to edit the actual main div I have the selectors off of.  I am kinda new at this and apologize for poor formatting or anything of that sort, But I would greatly appreciate some help on this!  I want the inner cicle to move the fastest, the middle to move slower, and the outer the slowest.

https://jsfiddle.net/wnmsfudo/1/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.loader {
  margin-top: -80px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 46vw;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.loader::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5px;
  left: 12.5px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: green;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.loader::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12.5px;
  left: -12.5px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: blue;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I was having issues formatting the jfiddle because I have never posted here before

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If the code is properly formatted to begin with, just paste it in, select it, and click the `{}` widget.  That shifts it right 4 spaces, causing it to be rendered as code.  I suggest avoiding use of tabs in the original, unless they're consistently set to 4 spaces per tab.

Comment: @JeffLearman Thanks for the tip I think I figured it out now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the entire `.loader` div rotates once every 2 seconds, and that the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements therefore rotate with it. Their own rotation is added to the parent's!

So the solution is to adapt the pseudo-elements' rotations so that they move relatively to the main element. The `::after` even needs to rotate in reverse if you want to make it appear slower.

```css
html, body {
  height: calc(100% - 16px);
}

.loader {
  margin-top: -80px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 46vw;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.loader::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5px;
  left: 12.5px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: green;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.loader::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12.5px;
  left: -12.5px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: blue;
  animation: spin 5s linear reverse infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought it had something to do with the fact that the bigger the circle, the more distance it had to cover in the same second(s) so they would have to go faster in the first place, but even if I gave `::after` a duration of 100s, it would still go faster. I didn't think of the pseudo-elements taking its parent transition myself, so I learned something new today, too. Thanks!